# Add variable in assembly instruction (asm inline C example)

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I would like to execute loop of asm lines of code.
Actually I am trying to read the CPUID of my core, need to read all the parameters of CPUID.
If I write 0 to eax register, then I will get the Manufacturer name and if I write 1 to eax then next set of CPUID information will received. And so on...
Now I would like to execute upto 15 set of asm instruction in order to get complete CPUID output.

Ex:

```
        unsigned int cpuid_reg[4];

        __asm__ volatile("mov $1, %eax");
        __asm__ volatile("cpuid" : "=a" (cpuid_reg[0]), "=b" (cpuid_reg[1]), "=c" (cpuid_reg[2]), "=d" (cpuid_reg[3]));
        printf("reg[0] 0x%x , cpuid_reg[1] 0x%x, cpuid_reg[2] 0x%x, cpuid_reg[3] 0x%x\n", cpuid_reg[0], cpuid_reg[1], cpuid_reg[2], cpuid_reg[3]);


        __asm__ volatile("mov $2, %eax");
        __asm__ volatile("cpuid" : "=a" (cpuid_reg[0]), "=b" (cpuid_reg[1]), "=c" (cpuid_reg[2]), "=d" (cpuid_reg[3]));
        printf("cpuid_reg[0] 0x%x , cpuid_reg[1] 0x%x, cpuid_reg[2] 0x%x, cpuid_reg[3] 0x%x\n", cpuid_reg[0], cpuid_reg[1], cpuid_reg[2], cpuid_reg[3]);
```

Instead of these two sets of code, I need to one set where I can write 0 to 15 into 'eax' register to get the complete CPUID data out.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use compiler intrinsic instead of inline assembly.

Comment: If you are using `__asm__ volatile`, and you’re writing user-space code that doesn't synchronize between threads, then `volatile` is almost always wrong and indicates that the asm block operands are not specified correctly.

Comment: How about using `__get_cpuid` from cpuid.h?

Comment: By the way, you will need a lot more than 15 cpuid calls to get complete information on a recent CPU. For some values of eax, you need to use cpuid multiple times with different values in ecx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read something like [this](https://wiki.osdev.org/CPUID) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID)

```
static inline void cpuid(int code, uint32_t *a, uint32_t *d) {
  asm volatile("cpuid":"=a"(*a),"=d"(*d):"a"(code):"ecx","ebx");
}

/** issue a complete request, storing general registers output as a string
 */
static inline int cpuid_string(int code, uint32_t where[4]) {
  asm volatile("cpuid":"=a"(*where),"=b"(*(where+1)),
               "=c"(*(where+2)),"=d"(*(where+3)):"a"(code));
  return (int)where[0];
}
```

Comment: You could write `"=b"(where[1])` like a normal person instead of `*(where+1)`.  But yes, an `"a"(code)` input constraint is the way to go.